# Is there any tools to do this kind of code formatting automatically

Tags: code-formatting, readability

It looks like a formal letter made with MS Word.
I wanna try this kind of format, but doing it manually is a waste of time

Is there any Code Editor/ extension/ something that can do this automatically

Found this on [codepen](https://codepen.io/yagoestevez/pen/bjZygz?editors=0010) by user yagoestevez.

```
// CSS
body {
  background          : $secondary-color;
  background          : repeating-linear-gradient(
                        60deg,
                        lighten( $key-color, 4% ),
                        lighten( $key-color, 4% ) 5px,
                        $key-color 5px,
                        $key-color 10px
                      );
  color               : $primary-color;
  font-family         : 'Merriweather', serif;
  padding             : 2rem;
  display             : flex;
  flex-direction      : column; 
  justify-content     : center;
  align-items         : center; 
}
```

```
  // JS
  drawTiles ( ) {
    const tiles = this.canvas.selectAll( 'g' )
      .data( this.treeLeaves )
      .enter( )
      .append( 'g' )
        .attr( 'class'    , 'tile-group' )
        .attr( 'transform', d => `translate( ${d.x0}, ${d.y0} )` );

    this.tile = tiles.append( 'rect' );
    this.tile.transition( )
      .attr( 'id'           , ( d, i ) => i )
      .attr( 'class'        , 'tile' )
      .attr( 'data-name'    , d => d.data.name )
      .attr( 'data-category', d => d.data.category )
      .attr( 'data-value'   , d => d.data.value )
      .attr( 'width'        , d => d.x1 - d.x0 )
      .attr( 'height'       , d => d.y1 - d.y0 );

    const mask = tiles.append( 'clipPath' )
      .attr( 'id', ( d, i ) => `clipPath-${i}` )
      .append( 'use' )
      .attr( 'xlink:href', ( d, i ) => `#${i}` );

    const tileText = tiles.append( 'text' )
      .attr( 'clip-path', ( d, i ) => `url( "#clipPath-${i}" )` )
      .attr( 'class', 'tile-text' )
      .attr( 'x', 5 )
      .attr( 'y', 15 )
      .text( d => d.data.name );

    return this;
  }
```

**Edit**

Its like the tool "Prettier" + extra whitespace to align the punctuation marks between each line of code

```
:
for example :
like        :
this        :
colon mark  :

, & =>
.attr( 'or'   , comma => {} )
.attr( 'like' , and   => {} )
.attr( 'this' , arrow => {} )
```

Unlike usual

```
:
for example :
like :
this :
colon mark :

, & =>
.attr( 'or' , comma => {} )
.attr( 'like' , and => {} )
.attr( 'this' , arrow => {} )
```

So, if any longer words added, it gets automatically inserts white spaces

Comment: This is explicitly off-topic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you use VSCode, the best plugin to achieve this formatting functionality is called Prettier. You can easily download in in the "Extensions" section on the left hand side of the IDE. Or alternatively, you can download it from:

https://prettier.io/docs/en/plugins.html